# PHP looping through an array to dynamically create a url

Tags: php

I have a list of data as json which I have decoded in php. I am trying to loop through the array to dynamically display its contents in a url which will display a google chart diagram in PHP. The contents of the data are saved in a php variable $value and $label with concatenation to join the string.

so my url looks somthing like this.

```
$url = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:' **. $value .** '&chs=375x150&chl=' **. $label .** '&chco=4D89F9,009900,FF9900,FF7F7F,FFD088,8FA3D6';

$url = urlencode(**$url**);
```

Everything looks fine except the image can not be rendered in the php file due to a trailing (,) colon sign.

Here is the full url after being encoded. In bold are the contents of $value

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=**t:0.3,1.4,65.3,1.0,4.3,0.5,**&chs=375x150&chl=CBD%7CCBN%7CTHC%7CCBC%7CCBG%7CTHCV%7C&chco=4D89F9,009900,FF9900,FF7F7F,FFD088,8FA3D6
```

You can see after the last value of 0.5 there is a trailing (,) comma sign and I dont know how to get rid of it. When I remove this last comma the image renders itself on the page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: urlencode won't add commas. It'll be there already in `$value`, so you need to fix whatever's generating the string in `$value`.

Comment: You need to show us the code generating `$value`.

Comment: this is the code:  $value .=  $data['profiling'][0][$i]['value1'];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple rtrim() should be what you need.

```
rtrim($value, ',');
```

Just do it before you concatenate the URL.

[PHP docs on rtrim()](https://www.php.net/rtrim)

Comment: I tried that and I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out my problem. And i feel pretty dumb for this, but I wasnt even connected to my remote server via ftp. So the changes made with the rtrim() function were not seen.

Anyways rtrim() did the job!.